# UWP Button present on every page

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Button should have the same functionality no matter what is the current page in Content. Is there a way to do this besides creating a button for every page?

[image: UWP button on every page]

Comment: Please share code explaining what you tried and what didn't work. As long as your button is outside of the Frame element that's hosting your pages it will stick around.

Comment: You can use app bar which can be available on every page through app.xaml

Answer (score 1):

Frame class can be used to host a Page. So you can put your menu and buttons in a new page that use a frame to host the content pages. The host page should look like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="menu" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button x:Name="someButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

You can show a content page using this:

```
mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(ContentPage));
```